# What is the relationship between NFS and caching?

Tags: caching, nfs

This seems like it should be blindingly obvious, but I cannot see the answer. Does NFS have caching? How does it work?  Does it simply leverage your operating system/filesystem caching? Does it depend on the client or server you are using?

I'm using NFS as a client on Solaris with no special mount options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NFS itself does not have caching, however your operating system may do some caching at the filesystem level.

From RFC 1813:

> The NFS version 3 protocol does not
>   define a policy for caching on the
>   client or server. In particular, there
>   is no support for strict cache
>   consistency between a client and
>   server, nor between different clients.

http://www.unixcoding.org/NFSCoding explains some of the practical issues with NFS caching.